# Android: Custom Gallery Activity

Tags: android, fragment, gallery

I am creating a custom gallery activity  on the left side will have a tools panel and the right is where the preview image with list of thumbnails at the bottom.

Inside the tools, we have an option which let the user to click into full screen mode so the right side will be shown in full screen.

This is my first time doing this. I am wondering Fragment is the best solutions to do it.

The left fragment are the tool panel and the right fragment contains the gallery. When the full screen button in the left fragment was clicked, the left fragment's width became 0dp whereas the right fragment took the whole area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard android-navigation drawer, where you can have your "tools"/widgets on a drawer panel and show the gallery in the container fragment.
or you can have a custom-design something like this: [sattelite-menu](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/811)
to have tools and display gallery as usual.
I have developed a similar app : [blimp-github](https://github.com/AkdeBoss/blimp)

Fragments are best solution to have if your app has very few screens where user is expected to swipe-navigate(makes it much simpler),
hope it helps....